# executing python program from cmd and php

Tags: php, cmd, xampp

```
exec("cd /d c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube");
exec("python  main.py > c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\out.txt");
```

I have written code in php so that it takes a python program and executes and it saves the result in out.txt but it is not working
I did the same thing from cmd it is working where am i going wrong

Comment: Doing `cd` doesn't mean that next `exec` will be called from target directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either

```
exec("python  c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\main.py > c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\out.txt");
```

or

```
exec("cd /d c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube && python main.py > c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\out.txt");
```

Because cd will not retain its directory over multiple exec() statements.

Comment: i have replaced it but the output of main.py is not saving into the output.txt .how to save the output of .py into txt file using cmd from php

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
exec("cd /d c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube && python main.py > c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\out.txt");
```

Comment: i have replaced it but output of main.py is not writting in to output.txt

Comment: Try 
 `exec("cd /d c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube && python -V > c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\out.txt");`
If this writes the python version into your file, then your main.py file doesn't output anything.
Else your OS doesn't find python when called from php

Comment: print("hiiiii ponna") this is main.py   this is php   <?php
 $code=$_POST["code"];
 $filename_code="main1.py";
 $out="output.txt";
 $file_code=fopen($filename_code,"w+");
 fwrite($file_code,$code);
 fclose($file_code);
     //exec("chmod 777 $out");
 //$out=fopen("output.txt","w+");
 
 exec("cd /d c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube && python -V > c:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\out.txt");
 echo file_get_contents("output.txt");
 fclose($out);
?>       where iam going wrong i have writtten a html by post and it submits from that i am trying to exec the python please help

Comment: You are trying to write to a file "out.txt" and then you are trying to read the content of "output.txt"

Comment: yes but the writng is not happing into out.txt plz helpme

Comment: Try to exec python including its full path (c:/programs/Python/python -V) or wherever your Phyton binary lives on your OS.